# Magento Buy x Get Y only works with the same product

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Using That rule , works only with the same product with qty > = 4. If i have 5 products from same category , separate order , the rule doesn't works.

Conditions:

```
if all conditions true
  if a item is found in the cart with all of the se conditions true:
    category is 76
```

Actions:

```
Apply: buy x get y
amout value: 1
discount max product: 0
qty products ( buy x ): 3

if all conditions all true:
 category is 76
```